# Unsupported MEDIA TYPE: 415 error Spring-rest webservices

Tags: java, spring, web-services, rest, spring-mvc

I created a restful web application using spring-rest api. I get unsupported media type error when I try to run my application from post-mater chrome plugin or Advanced rest client.

I am posting the different files as follows:

1) web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
<servlet>
 <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
 <servlet-class>
  org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
 </servlet-class>
 <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
 <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

2) rest-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
 xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd">
 <context:component-scan base-package="com.mayank.spring.mvc" />
 <mvc:annotation-driven />
  </beans>
```

3) Controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/service/greeting")
public class SpringServiceController {
 @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public  @ResponseBody Employee getGreeting(@RequestBody Employee name) {
     if(name!=null){
         name.setEmployeeId(name.getEmployeeId()+1);
         name.setEmployeeName(name.getEmployeeName());
     }
     return name;
 }
}
```

4) Employee bean

```
public class Employee {
private int employeeId;
private String employeeName;
}
```

How I am sending the data using post master

[image]

Where am I going wrong? I tried almost everything :(

Comment: You forgot to add getters and setters to Employee.

Comment: @JBNizet I didn't include them here but they were included in my code. :(

Comment: Then post your real code. It matters. Do you have jackson in the webapp libraries? If you don't, Spring won't unmarshal JSON.

Comment: @JBNizet:   I am using maven and I have included all the jackson libraries but still I cannot get rid of 415 error. Can you look at my code once? My id is: mayank.placid@gmail.com

Answer (score -1):

Error code `415` is `Unsupported Media Type`, meaning it doesn't understand plain text vs json vs xml.  You should put, in your `@RequestMapping` on the method

```
produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE}
```

and

```
consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE}
```

Then, in your client make sure in the headers you put `Accept = application/json` and `Content-type = application/json`.